# SQL Select - adding field to Select is changing the results

Tags: sql-server-2008, having-clause

I'm stumped by this SQL problem that I suspect will be easy pickings for someone out there.

I have a table that contains rows representing several daily lists of ranked items.  The relevent fields are as follows: ID, ListID, ItemID, ItemName, ItemRank, Date.

I have a query that returns the items that were on a list yesterday but not today (Items Off List) as follows:

```
Select ItemID, ListID, ItemName, convert(varchar(10),MAX(date),101) as date, COUNT(ItemName) as days_on_list 
From Table 
Group By ItemID, ListID, ItemName
Having Max(date) = DATEADD("d",-1,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)) and ListID = 1
Order By ListID, ItemName, COUNT(ItemName)
```

Basically I'm looking for records where the max date is yesterday.  It works fine and shows the number of days each item was previously on the list (although not necessarily consecutively, but that's fine for now).

The problem is when I try to add ranking to see what yesterday's rank was. I tried the following:

```
Select ItemID, ListID, ItemName, ranking, convert(varchar(10),MAX(date),101) as date, COUNT(ItemName) as days_on_list 
From Table
Group By ItemID, ListID, ItemName, ranking
Having Max(date) = DATEADD("d",-1,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)) and ListID = 1
Order By ListID, ItemName, ranking, COUNT(ItemName)
```

This returns a great deal more records than the previous query so something isn't right with it.  I want the same number of records, but with the ranking included.  I can get the rank by doing a self-join with a subquery and getting records where the ItemID occurs yesterday but not today - but then I don't know how to get the Count any more.

Appreciation in advance for any help with this.

======== SOLVED ==============

```
Select ItemID, ListID, ItemName, ranking, convert(varchar(10),MAX(date),101) as date, (Select COUNT(ItemName) From Table T3 Where T3.ItemID = T.ItemID and T3.ListID = 1) as days_on_list
from Table T
Where date = DATEADD("d",-1,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)) and ListID = 1 and T.ItemID Not In
(select T.ItemID from Table T
    join Table T2 on T.ItemID = T2.ItemID and T.ListID = T2.ListID
    where T.date = DATEADD("d",-1,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)) and T2.date = convert
(varchar(10),getdate(),101) and T.ListID = 1)
Group by ItemID, ListID, ItemName, ranking
```

Basically, what I did was create a subquery that finds all items that appear in both days, and finds items that appeared yesterday but are not in the set of items that appeared both days.  Then I was able to do the aggregate function and grouping correctly.  I would NOT be surprised if this is more convoluted than necessary but I understand it and can modify it as needed and performance doesn't seem to be an issue.

Thanks to all again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem probably is that ranking is different for items that would in the first question get grouped.

So when you add ranking to the group by there are more groups than before.

If this is the case and you still want the same amount of rows you have to include ranking after grouping witn a wrapping question and then you also have to decide if you like min ranking or max ranking from the matching rows.

Comment: Each item can only appear once per day per list and similarly, each ranking can only appear once, so I don't think min and max will be issues.  By a 'wrapping question' do you mean taking the first set of results (without ranking) and making it a subquery in a larger query?

Comment: This sounds like an approach I can wrestle with.  Will try it and get back to you.  Thanks for the pointer so far.

Comment: Success!  I will append the working query to the question and attempt to describe what I did as best as possible in case this is of help to someone in the future.  Thanks, David...this was exactly the nudge I needed to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

Your initial query without ranking groups by three fields.
Your query, with the ranking added, groups by four fields.
So your grouping is by a finer grain and will therefore most likely give you more records.

I would need to see a sample dataset and sample desired values before suggestion a query solution.

Comment: not sure the best way to post a dataset but perhaps I can describe it a bit better.  Simplest form, there is a list of n ranked items each day.  An item can appear at ranking x one day, ranking y the next day, and be off the list on day 3.  Items can not appear twice on the same list on the same day.

Comment: Let's assume my original query returns 3 items out of 100 that were on the list yesterday but not today.  I have confirmed that is correct.  My second query  (with ranking) returns 77 items.  The rankings are correct for yesterday, but most of these appeared today so the Max(date) is apparently not working correctly anymore.

Comment: I'm suspect the extra records appear because the ranking is different on the two days, and the ones that don't maintained the same ranking...if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the Count without using a Group By by the Over clause.

```
With Items As
    (
    Select ItemID, ListID, ItemName, Ranking, [Date]
        , Row_Number() Over( Partition By ItemID, ListID, ItemName Order By [Date] Desc ) As Num
        , Count(ItemName) Over ( Partition By ItemId, ListId, ItemName ) As DaysOnList
    From Table As T
    Where T.[Date] = DateAdd(d, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
        And Not Exists  (
                        Select 1
                        From Table As T2
                        Where T2.ItemID = T.ItemID
                            And T2.ListId = T.ListId
                            And T2.[Date] > T.[Date]
                        )
    )
Select ItemID, ListID, ItemName, LastDate, Ranking
From Items
Where Num = 1
Order By ListID, ItemName, DaysOnList
```

Comment: Thomas, I'm not familiar with the Over clause yet but am looking. In the mean time, I tried running this in SSMS and got several errors. For one thing, did you mean to put two Where clauses one after the other or should that second one be an And? Also, DaysOnList at the bottom is not being recognized from it's definition up top but perhaps that's related. Finally, T is not recognized in the central Select but I am able to make it work as a self-join...just not sure if that's breaking the rest of the query as you intended it. Thanks.

Comment: @nycdan - The double Where was a typo. There should be an And there.

Comment: @nycdan - I'm not sure why it does not like the `T` alias. From what I can see, that's correct. The second select is not a self-join but rather a correlated subquery to itself to ensure that there are no values with a date greater than yesterday for the given Item and List. That's the equivalent of your `Having(Max(Date)) = yesterday` logic.

Comment: Thomas, I got it working as described above, but I'm still interested in learning how to make this work too.  Thanks for the pointer and this gives me something else to learn from this (if I can ever find that kind of time!).

Comment: @nycdan - The Over clause is a window function which lets you operate on a subset of the data without a formal Group By. Row_Number, creates a sequential list of numbers with each grouping of the partition list (so on each new group it restarts) and Count obviously works like it normally does only it restarts counting over each new group. The reason for using Row_Number is to ensure that I only get one row for each ItemId, ListId and ItemName group since I'm no longer using a Group By.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, and I wish I had the reputation to comment this, but is the "ranking" item in the group by statement necessary?  Given this context, it doesn't look like it should be.

Comment: Yes.  I would agree from a logical perspective, but if I don't include each field there, I get the error 'Column 'Table.ranking' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: Is it returning results containing the ranking for every day stored? You may have to create a view that does something along the lines of "select ranking, itemid, listid from table where day=yesterday" and then join your query results on that view by itemid and listid.